# How can I force an iTunes Connect password reset?

Tags: app-store-connect

We've got an account at work that was setup by someone else in the past.  It controls our apps in the app store.  We'd like to make some changes, but do not know the password.  I've tried the "Forgot your Apple ID/password" thing, but am not getting anywhere.  "security questions" mode asks us things we don't know and the email authentication doesn't work (as in, we never receive the reset request at the account's e-mail address).  I've confirmed that e-mail method reset requests make it to our domain fine by doing it on my own account.  It just doesn't seem to work for this particular very important account (which I get forwarded to me, and have tested fine from other domains).

Is it possible that the Apple ID e-mail address is different from the one that the reset requests are going to?  If so, what's the procedure to get that fixed?  Is there a specific department at Apple I should contact?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find another user here that still had access, so that they could add my account, from which I could make all required changes.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have shipping apps in the store, you will be able to call developer relations and begin the process to get things reset.

https://developer.apple.com/contact/ and https://developer.apple.com/contact/phone.php

Even consumer Apple ID have the ability to set a separate email address for emails about resetting the security questions and emailing administrative changes, so the account in question might very well be set up in that manner.

While you are on the line, you can ask about setting up multiple accounts for your business so that several people are listed to do certain tasks for you.

Comment: Played some voicemail tag with Apple, never managed to make connections, apparently they're working on a different schedule from us.